# Remove padding of c3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a c3 line chart with a category x axis.

```js
 var data = {
  x: "x",
        columns: [
   ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
   ["data1", 0, 1, 2, 3],
   ["data2", 3, 2, 1, 0],
  ],
  labels: true
    };
 var axis = {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
   tick: {
    centered: true,
   },
   padding: 0
        },
  y: {
   padding: {bottom:5, top:5}
  }
    };
 ccChartL = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#ccLdiv',
  data: data,
  axis: axis,
  transition:{duration: 1000}
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="ccLdiv"></div>
```

At the left there is a gap between the beginning of the line and the axis. Same at the right. How do i remove it? I want the beginning of the lines, category a, to be at the x value 0. I tried a view answers of Stackoverflow, but it didn't work. Padding is set to 0. If i set it to any positive value, it just narrows down more.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative padding of -0.5 or slightly less (-0.49) will get rid of these gaps.

However it will slightly cut off your first and last labels, you may need a formula of sorts e.g.

```
padding: -0.5 - (0.01 * no_of_datapoints)
```